# passing 2 inputStreams to symfony Process

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to execute a diff between two remote files with symfony Process.
Executing the command from command line works, but when I try using php I have an empty output..

```
$process = new Process('diff <(ssh user@remote1 "cat /my/remote1/file.txt") <(ssh user@remote2 "cat /my/remote2/file.txt")');
$process->run();
$output = $process->getOutput();
```

So I tried with setInput:

```
$process = new Process('diff');
$process->setInput('(ssh user@remote1 "cat /my/remote1/file.txt")');
$process->setInput('(ssh user@remote2 "cat /my/remote2/file.txt")');
$process->run();
$output = $process->getOutput();
```

but still same result..

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Have You tried get content of files by PHP and then set them as input? Documentation not mention that bash commands can be used as input nor it will be executed.
Additionally: what are You using to pass parameters to `setInput`? I see there is a class `InputStream` - which could make a magic.

Comment: I successfully got the content of the files separately, but I still have issues sending them to the diff process..

Comment: Could You use `mustRun()` method instead of `run()` and catch any failures? Maybe there will be something usefull? In docs You have an example of that call.